# The column or argument definition is invalid in DB2 razor

Tags: razor, db2

> Hello everyone, I have a problem to get the result use this formula
>   **LISTAGG** at Razor in DB2. Can you help me what the problem with this formula and how to solve it?

This is my Query:

```
SELECT 
   REFRV_REV_CODE
,  LISTAGG(Cast(REFRV_DESCRIPTION as VARCHAR), ', ') AS Groups
FROM
    tref_revenue_code
GROUP BY REFRV_REV_CODE
```

[image]

Comment: Never put error messages in bitmaps, because they are not searchable. Instead, copy and paste the exact error message as plain-text and edit that into the question.

Comment: What Db2 platform and version are you using?

Comment: thank you. i hope you can edit and correct my question properly

Comment: You should be able to edit your question yourself

Answer (score 0):

The error [SQL0604N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic3.html#sql0604n) refers to an invalid type precision. I would assume that the **VARCHAR** is at fault. Have you tried to restrict the VARCHAR to a length, e.g., use **VARCHAR(200)** instead of VARCHAR alone?

Comment: hello data_henrik, i has use VARCHAR(200) and i got the error message. The error message are ERROR: No function or procedure was found with the specified
name and compatible arguments.

DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440,
SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=FUNCTION;LISTAGG, DRIVER=3.57.82

Answer (score 0):

`LISTAGG` is only supported on Db2 for LUW from version 10.1 onwards, your error message implies that you are using an earlier version.

Your code works on e.g. Db2 11.

```
WITH tref_revenue_code(REFRV_REV_CODE, REFRV_DESCRIPTION) AS (VALUES (1,'a'),(1,'b'))
SELECT
     REFRV_REV_CODE
,    LISTAGG(Cast(REFRV_DESCRIPTION as VARCHAR), ', ') AS Groups 
FROM 
    tref_revenue_code
GROUP BY 
    REFRV_REV_CODE
```

returns

```
 REFRV_REV_CODE GROUPS
 -------------- ------
              1 a, b
```